# Pareto optimum in game matrix

Tags: game-theory

I have to find Pareto optimum squares in game matrix. They are marked in following picture [image]

What questions do I have to ask myself for every square to decide if it is Pareto optimum?

Why square E/A (5,4) is not optimal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [Pareto optimality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_efficiency) is a state of allocation of resources in which it is impossible to make any one individual better off without making at least one individual worse off.

E&A with a value $(5,4)$ can be improved to F&D with a value of $(5,5)$ since the second player is better off and the first player is not worse off.

Similarly F&A can be Pareto improved to F&B or F&D or G&D, and you can find examples of improvement without worsening for all the cases without red rings, but you cannot for any of the cases with red rings.

Comment: why G&C is Pareto, comparing 2,2 and 6,3 both worse off 6 to 2 and 3 to 2!

Comment: @Fay007: G&C gives $(6,3)$ and $6$ is better than all of $N_1$'s other outcomes apart from E&B $(8,1)$, which is worse for $N_2$.  So G&C is Pareto optimal.